# Can I carry a ceramic knife in the cabin baggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

On the [airlines website](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/travel-information/baggage-restrictions/), knives are listed as restricted items (but are not prohibited).
I do not have any checked in luggage and am travelling from Darwin (Australia) to Singapore in Singapore Airlines. Can I carry a ceramic knife with me ?

Comment: Any weapons, whether real or replicas, are not allowed on board. And as usual, things are a bit different in planet USA.

Comment: lol of course not, no.  it makes no difference at all what material the knife is made of.

Comment: Do you mean "can" in the sense of "will I be able to sneak one?" or in the sense of "I am allowed to do it?" In the 1st case, no, since ceramic knifes still have some metal in them to be detectable, and, 2, no too, although there was some talk about allowing really small knifes like a Swiss army knife, until they backed off.

Comment: Why would you want a ceramic knife in the first place, except for concealment from metal detectors?

Comment: @iconoclast Ceramic knives are a [standard type of kitchen knife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_knife) — they can supposedly stay sharp longer than metal blades.

Comment: I have seen children's water gun which was obviously a toy being taken away on Kuwait airport.

Comment: What is the reason why knives are forbidden on planes? Now, does it make any difference if the knife is made of ceramic?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Restricted items may only be carried in checked luggage. However, Singapore Airlines permits you to check at least 30 kg for free, so I would suggest you simply check your carry-on luggage.

Answer (score 20):

Knives don't go in carry-on, period. (maybe really small ones, depending on the country.) The material the knife is made of doesn't matter. Ceramic, wood (ebony will hold a nice edge), bone, flint and so on have all made fine weapons millenia before steel.

If you do pack a non-metallic weapon in the darker corners of your carry-on, and they find it, you could be up on an "artful concealment" charge, which is usually very serious. In contrast, a Crocodile Dundee grade Bowie knife will usually not cause any substantial grief - hiding the beast is impossible, you'll just get pointed back to baggage check.

Comment: in fact that knife may well land you an arrest for possession of an illegal weapon, depending on the country you're in.

Comment: True, if it's not legal to carry it on the street. But I'm trying to illustrate concealed vs. non-concealed(able) restricted items.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that looks like a weapon is not allowed in the carry on, and this is pre 9-11. A long time ago I once caused quite a stir at LHR and EWR with a key chain shaped as a gun, the size of a thumb.

Comment: They're not entirely consistent.  Before 9-11 I forgot to pack my Leatherman tool in my checked luggage, and they found it, looked at it, and let me keep it with me in the cabin.  I was very surprised by this.  However, when I was about 7 or 8 years old, I had an obviously plastic and obviously fake space-age looking toy "gun" confiscated from me because they said it could fool people (though only the blind and stupid could have been fooled by it).

Comment: I completely agree.  A few years ago they confiscated my miniature screwdrivers while they failed to notice the big screwdriver in the same backpack.

Comment: The TSA agent working then already had all the big screwdrivers he needed ;)

Comment: January 2000 I bought a broad sword in Spain and tried to put it in checked luggage on the return to the US. They made me take it as a carry on and refused to let me take it as checked luggage.

Comment: How about the battleship piece from Monopoly?